# .NET framework 4.5 loads default edit template on GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5

I've created a gridview with edit feature. On clicking the gridview row edit image, it makes the custom edit panel visible and the user can edit and save the gridview row data or s/he can click the cancel button  without any updates. It works perfectly fine with `.NET framwork 2.0.`

But, the problem lies with the `.NET framework 4.5` -

> when the user clicks the cancel or save button, instead of loading the
>   normal gridview, it loads the default edit template on the top of
>   gridview row where the user had clicked before.

So, how can I solve this problem? This happens in all the Gridviews used in our ASP.NET website.

Here's the original Gridview Row:  [Original GridRow](http://www.screencast.com/t/nC5C1XoCo3)

[image]

Here's the custom edit panel with save/cancel: [Custom Edit Panel](http://www.screencast.com/t/CaqDIoSj)

[image]

Here's error: [Default Template loaded](http://www.screencast.com/t/U8CjXHFoIT)

[image]

Comment: Show me the code where you are overriding the edit item template default behaviour in your grid view row data-bound event.As well as a snippet of your mark-up.

Comment: I've used OnRowEditing event in the GridView

Comment: Here is the link http://pastebin.com/CN8muLrQ

Comment: And in the OnRowEditing event handler, I've made custom edit panel visible and gridview as visible false : http://pastebin.com/WvzWx4E5 @AbideMasaraure

Comment: Thanks.I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I usually achieve what you are trying to do in the row databound event.

Try setting up your grid view like this

```
<asp:Gridview id="ClientManagementGridView runat="server"/>
<columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
 <itemtemplate>
 //put edit button here
</itemtemplate>
<edititemtemplate>
// put  your update and cancel buttons here
</edititemtemplate>
</asp:Templatefield>
<asp:templatefield>
<itemtemplate>
<aspTextBox Text='<#Eval("ClientId") %>' runat="server" />
</itemtemplate>
 <edititemtemplate>
 <asp:Panel id="EditPanel">
 //your panel contents
 </asp:Panel>
</edititemtemplate>
</asp:templateField>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Name" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Name" />
    </columns>
<asp:GridView>
```

Now in your row data bound event of your gridview put this magic piece of code

```
  If e.Row.RowState.ToString().Contains("Edit") Then
            Dim editGrid As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
            Dim colSpan As Integer = editGrid.Columns.Count
            e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = True
            e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = True
            For i As Integer = 2 To colSpan - 1
                e.Row.Cells(i).Visible = False
                e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.Clear()
            Next

            e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("ColSpan") = (colSpan).ToString()
  End if
```

As you can see I am overriding the default edit item template by clearing its default controls and then changing the column span of the cell to fit my  custom edit panel.As well as hiding cells I want to be hidden.